# creating facebook event and showing on map

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I am able to create a facebook event using facebook developer api . But I also need to display the map showing the corresponding location when I view it on facebook. In order to achieve this I passed the latitude/longitude(both as part of venue object and separately) along with the location but it does not seem to work. Can someone please help

Regards
Vivek